# Need to delete data from an access database in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I need to delete certain data from an access database when a button is clicked and it keeps throwing an error relating to the executeNonquery(), I'm really new to this I would appreciate any help, here is my code

```
  private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection myDb = new OleDbConnection(connectionString + DBFile);
        myDb.Open();
        if (ComboBoxSelection.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = myDb;


            foreach (DataGridViewRow myRow in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                string query = "DELETE FROM Clients WHERE ClientID = '{int.Parse(txtEdit.text)}'";
                command.CommandText = query;

            }
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myDb.Close();

        }


        else if (ComboBoxSelection.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = myDb;


            foreach (DataGridViewRow myRow in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                string query = "DELETE FROM Clients WHERE ClientID = '{txtEdit.text}'";
                command.CommandText = query;



            }
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myDb.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Step one is show the **full** error. Edit the question to add the text of the exception and inner exception if applicable, no screenshots.

Comment: What is the error message? Try not using apostrophe delimiters if ClientID is a number type field.

Comment: This is a string _'{int.Parse(txtEdit.text)}'_ not the result of the parse method. If you want to use [this syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) you need to prefix the whole string with the $ symbol

Comment: String interpolation requires `$`, so like `$"DELETE FROM......"`;

Comment: And as second problem could you explain why do you loop over datagrid.SelectedRows but try to execute always the same query with the same textbox value?

Answer (score 2):

Making a lot of assumptions about what you are trying to do, which is delete from the database every client id in the selected rows. This is a big assumption since you are using the same `TextBox` in your sample code for each row but I'm guessing this is a work in progress and you were going to get there eventually.

First, commands and connections are disposable resources so you should make sure they are Disposed when you are done with them. A common way to do that is to instantiate them in `using` blocks as I show below.

Second, you should always use parameterized queries, never concatenate strings together. I don't know if `ClientID` is a string or a number, you appear to use it both ways, but if someone typed `' OR 1=1; --` into the text box while the combobox was on index 1 then you could end up with everything deleted.

Lastly, you have a lot of duplication. Based on my assumptions, you can clean up your code to this:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "DELETE FROM Clients WHERE ClientID = @ClientID";

    using (OleDbConnection myDb = new OleDbConnection(connectionString + DBFile))
    using (OleDbCommand command = myDb.CreateCommand())
    {
        int clientid = 0;

        command.CommandText = query;

        OleDbParameter parClientID = new OleDbParameter("@ClientID", OleDbType.Integer);
        command.Parameters.Add(parClientID);

        myDb.Open();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow myRow in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            //Assume your client id is in a cell of the row? Zero for first, One for second, etc.
            if (int.TryParse(myRow.Cells[0].ToString(), out clientid))
            {
                parClientID.Value = clientid;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```